# Multiple layers of div on the same row issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make multiple divs one over another cause I'm doing sort of a uneven 1 row grid.
My html :

```
<div class="section-100pc">
<div class="section-spec">
    <div class="wrapper-spec">
        <div class="texte-spec">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumit amet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-photo-spec"></div>
```

And my css :

```
    .section-100pc {
    width:100%;
    background:gray;
}
.section-spec {
    width:50%;
}
.section-photo-spec {
    width:50%;
    background:red;
    z-index:999;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    min-height:300px;
}
.wrapper-spec {
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.texte-spec {
    width:50%;
    background:green;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 30px 0;
    float:left;
}
```

So I made 1 100% section that contains 2 divs. both got a width of 50%. Inside the left 50% div, I inserted a 1200px wrapper with position absolute cause I need to align some text with the rest of the website in that div. Inside that 1200px, I created another 50% div with the text in it.
On the right side (the other 50% div in the 100% section), it stays at 50%, no text in it. I will add a background-image later on.

Kind of hard to explain, but I'm sure you guys will understand by seeing my fiddle or code here.

My issue = The right 50% div goes under the 100% main section. It is not on the same row as the rest. How can I acheive this? Everything needs to be on the same row.

(I added some jQuery so the parent div expands with the child div inside because of the "absolute" position)

Thanks a lot, and again, sorry, it's kind of hard to explain and english is not my first language!

Cheers!

http://jsfiddle.net/ry9gt0Lt/2/

Comment: Keep in mind that when you set a relative width on a container, it is not the width of the page that it's relative to, but the width of the parent container. So, when you set width: 50%, if the div you're setting it on is the top-level div, it'll be 50% of the page width. However, if you set it on the next div down, it'll be 50% of that parent div.

Also, you have a window that is less than 2400px wide with a container that is 1200px wrapped in another container that's set to 50%. Unless your window is 2400px wide, the parent will be larger than 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left; to section-spec class:

something like:

```
.section-spec {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

and make sure that z-index for the red block is greater than z-index for green box and you will be good

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried and it works partially. I need the parent 100% div to adjust itself depending on the height of the div with the text in it. And I need the big red section to adjust itself depending on the "section-spec" height too. Just so if I add more text in that div, the rest will adjust.